# Running certain APDUs fails, stating Failed to transmit with protocol T0. Falscher Parameter

Tags: driver, smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader, pyscard

I'm having issues accessing SLE4428 cards under Windows 10 using an ACS ACR38U-I1, Python 3.7 and pyscard. I'm using the latest driver the manufacturer currently offers for Windows.

The main problem is that running certain APDUs fails, stating `Failed to transmit with protocol T0. Falscher Parameter` (= wrong parameter, error code 87). Running the exact same code with the same reader on a Raspberry Pi works flawlessly however. I have not installed any specific drivers on the Pi.

I'm using this code for running APDUs:

```python
    from smartcard.CardType import AnyCardType
    from smartcard.CardConnection import CardConnection
    from smartcard.CardRequest import CardRequest
    
    cardtype = AnyCardType()
    cardrequest = CardRequest(timeout=1, cardType=cardtype)
    cardservice = cardrequest.waitforcard()
    cardservice.connection.connect(CardConnection.T0_protocol)
    apdu = [0xff, 0xb0, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff] #READ_MEMORY_CARD
    response, sw1, sw2 = cardservice.connection.transmit(apdu, CardConnection.T0_protocol)
    print('response: ', response, ' status words: ', "%x %x" % (sw1, sw2))
```

This code works fine on both platforms. Trying to authenticate using
`[0xff, 0x20, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0xff, 0xff]`
however results in the crash described **on Windows**. I've tried the stock Windows driver as well as playing around with different protocols, no success.

Another weird behaviour that is exclusive to Windows: When inserting a card, the reader's LED flashes quickly and it takes around 9 seconds before the card can be accessed at all.

This is the first time I'm trying to interface with hardware, so it's probably something obvious, but I cannot figure it out. I'd appreciate any input and/or recommendations for (still available) readers that are known to work in this configuration.

Comment: WRT to the flashing: you probably need to disable to disable the certificate propagation service in Windows and see if that helps. With regards to the authenticate APDU: the 5th byte is valued 0x03, which means that Nc is valued 3, but you only supply 2 bytes in the command data (0xFF and 0xFF).

Comment: Disabling the certificate propagation service helps somewhat with the unresponsive reader: With a freshly plugged in reader and disabled service, the first 3-4 cards still cause a flashing LED and are slow to access. After these first few though, the cards are instantly accessible and the readers LED stays lit.

Answer (score 0):

APDU CLA value 'FF' isn't allowed according to ISO 7816-4. Manufacturers of PC/SC readers sometime support APDU commands with CLA=FF to implement some specific functions like access to MIFARE cards or tuning of communication protocol settings.

Comment: The SLE4428 mentioned in the question **is** a memory card... Given the question I wonder if this isn't already known by the author.